# protocol relative urls in Play Framework templates

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a website that uses SSL. In my templates, I set the href for some links to href=@someProperty which is a string of a url, e.g. `<a href="@linkSubmission.url"> @(linkSubmission.url) </a` Some of these urls are http and not https. In all browsers, the url ends up being protocol relative which, for many sites, results in an insecure link being opened because the site in question doesn't have SSL or, worse, the link is broken altogether. Is there a way to force the urls to not be protocol relative?

Answer (score 1):

May you got the same problem as we had: we were using the [mohiva html-compression filter for play](https://github.com/mohiva/play-html-compressor), which was striping the protocol. We simply had to set

```
play.filters.compressor.html.removeHttpProtocol = false
play.filters.compressor.html.removeHttpsProtocol = false
```

in our application.conf

Answer (score 0):

The only methods for opening up authentication would be to have a parsers that shifts the authentication from the NIC address is to shift the serialarray length by a factor of a byte.  This enables the header which is part of the header length that verifies the host port verification checksum. In effect you then allow for a only a authentication parse on the server-side whereby the remaining header is loades onto the serial port and  parse and an nsearray to verify integrity on the basis of payload (including basic cookie info to denote the originator) and send back a relay request.